# ActionScript Dictionary to C#

Tags: c#, .net, actionscript

i'm working on converting an Action Sript class to C# and now i'm choosing a proper data types to replace `ActionScript` data Types ... and i wondered what is the best `C# datatype` to replace the `Dictionary Datatype` in Actionscript 
here's a sample code for example

```
public static const db:String = "http://dbpedia.org/resource/";
public static const rdf:String = "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#";
public static const skos:String = "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#";

private var prefixes:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

public function SPARQLQueryBuilder() {
        prefixes["db"] = db;
        prefixes["rdf"] = rdf;
        prefixes["skos"] = skos;
}
```

Comment: In C# you have the Dictionary class: var prefixes = new Dictionary<string, string>(); and then you can add items to it this way: prefixes["db"] = db;

Comment: Thanks @Ben, I will move the comment into an answer :)

Comment: @HadyElsahar, downvoted because you obviously havent looked or you would have found this yourself, as it has the same name in .Net as in ActionScript.

Comment: @ben i asked because there are other similar datatypes to use such as MAPS or Structures so i wondered what to use and of course i've searched and found the Dictionary Datatype in C#

Answer (score 2):

In C# you have the Dictionary class:

```
var prefixes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

and then you can add items to it this way:

```
prefixes["db"] = db;
prefixes["rdf"] = rdf;
prefixes["skos"] = skos;
```